# is it possible to color groups differently

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am planning to have different colors for each  element in the .I was just exploring if this is possible.

My code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#graphid").append("svg")
    .style("margin-left","30px")
    //.style("background-color","lavender")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("id","focusid")
     .style("background-color","#F8FCFB")
    //.call(zoom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var fo= d3.select("#focusid").style("background-color","azure");
    console.log(fo);

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("id","contextid")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


    var contx= d3.select("#contextid").style("background-color","lavender");   

 ............../
 ..............//
 .............///
```

the groups were not getting the colors set? What am i missing here?

Comment: do you have a JSFiddle  ?

Comment: AJ_91 http://fiddle.jshell.net/zua7L31d/4/

Comment: What is it youre trying to do ?

Comment: change the background color for the groups so that focus and context have different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to append a 'rect' to you SVG and fill that as you can't just fill a 'g'. So create a rectangle then append the focus to that rectangle. same with context :)

```
//create the rectangle to fill here 
var rect = svg.append('rect')
.attr('id', 'rect')
.style('fill', 'red')
.attr("height", height)
         .attr("width", width);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("id","focusid")
    //.call(zoom)

    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Ive done it for focus, leave it up to you to do context :)

Updated fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/zua7L31d/6/

Finished both them off :

Added a new rectangle for the 'context'

```
var contextRect = svg.append('rect')
.attr('id', 'rect2')
//.style('fill', 'red')
.attr("height", rect2Height)
         .attr("width", rect1Width)
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', rect1Height)
;
```

Final fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/zua7L31d/7/

Hope that helped :)